# LeetCode #512 Game Play Analysis MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, min

I was doing this question LeetCode #512
The original code I wrote was:

```
select a.player_id, a.device_id from 
(select player_id, device_id, min(event_date)
from Activity
group by player_id) a
```

My logic here is to firstly, filter out the minimal corresponding event date for each player. It seems that the code had selected the correct earliest date that I wanted, but failed to correspond the device id that matches that specific date. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix my code?

Thank you upfront for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query as below to select player_id,device_id corresponding to minimum event_Date.

```
select a.player_id, a.device_id from 
(select player_id, device_id, min(event_date)
from Activity
group by player_id,device_id) a
```

Alternatively use window function as below,

```
select a.player_id, a.device_id from 
(select player_id, device_id,event_Date,row_number() over (partition by player_id order by event_Date asc) AS rn
from Activity) a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it does not do the job.

Comment: can you show sample of your data and current output? Try the second query with window function.

Comment: Sample data: {"headers":{"Activity":["player_id","device_id","event_date","games_played"]},"rows":{"Activity":[[1,2,"2016-03-01",5],[1,2,"2016-05-02",6],[1,3,"2015-06-25",1],[3,1,"2016-03-02",0],[3,4,"2016-02-03",5]]}}

Comment: Current output: {"headers": ["player_id", "device_id"], "values": [[1, 2], [3, 1]]}

Comment: Expected: {"headers": ["player_id", "device_id"], "values": [[1, 3], [3, 4]]}

Comment: The window function does work! Thanks for your help!